# Form submit cause downloading

Tags: jquery, html, forms, http-post

I have a form:

```
<form id="auth_form" action="http:abcd/sub/SSO" method="post">
    //other input
    <input type="submit" value="Click to get Auth" />
</form>
```

and when the user click the button to submit, I will do something first before submit, adding some field to the form, like a timestamp to indicate the submitting time.

```
//javascript
$("#auth_form").submit(function(){
    //some thing to add to the form input
});
```

But now when I click the submit button, the page is not directed to the action page, but start a downloading instead. Download a file "SSO". What's hap happening?

Comment: Try changing "http:abcd" to "`http://abcd`".

Answer (score 1):

What does http:abcd/sub/SSO do? I am guessing that it takes a user login request and redirects to another url on successful authentication. Have you tried checking the response headers from the http:abcd/sub/SSO end-point, it sounds like this might not be sending the right content-type.

Comment: you are right, it is a auth system, I which to be directed to the SSO page.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong, `the page is not directed to the action page`.

The page is going to the action page and downloading the file SSO which the URL ends in.

Answer (score 0):

There is one possibilities 
when you post your form to given url  `http//:abcd/sub/SSO`  using post

```
<form id="auth_form" action="http://abcd/sub/SSO" method="post">
```

It may respond as a file attachment ..

so browser prompt dialog for download so first check ur `post` or change post url is not responding as a file .